# Scrapy rule SgmlLinkExtractor not working

Tags: python, html, scrapy

how can I get my rule to work in my crawlspider and to follow the links, I added this rule but its not working, nothing gets display but i don't get no error either. I comment out what my domains should look like in the code for my rule.

Rule #1

```
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\/company\/.*\?goback=.*'), callback='parse_item',follow=True)
   # looking for domains like in my rule:
   #http://www.linkedin.com/company/1009?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits
   #http://www.linkedin.com/company/1033?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits
```

I also tried this rule but did not work nothing happen no errors either: Rule #2

```
  rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\/company\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\?',)), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

code

```
class LinkedPySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'LinkedPy'
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
    start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results"]

    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\/company\/.*\?goback=.*'), callback='parse_item',follow=True)
   # looking for domains like in my rule:
   #http://www.linkedin.com/company/1009?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits
   #http://www.linkedin.com/company/1033?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits

    def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(
    url=self.login_page,
    callback=self.login,
    dont_filter=True
    )

  #  def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
  #      return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
    #"""Generate a login request."""
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'session_key': 'yescobar2012@gmail.com', 'session_password': 'yescobar01'},
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
    #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
    if "Sign Out" in response.body:
        self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
        # Now the crawling can begin..
        self.log('Hi, this is an response page! %s' % response.url)

        return Request(url='http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results')

    else:
        self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.


    def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = LinkedconvItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

output

```
C:\Users\ye831c\Documents\Big Data\Scrapy\linkedconv>scrapy crawl LinkedPy
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: linkedconv)
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMi
ddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scra
ped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
3
2013-07-15 12:05:15-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-15 12:05:16-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.linked
in.com/uas/login> (referer: None)
2013-07-15 12:05:16-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.
linkedin.com/nhome/> from <POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit>
2013-07-15 12:05:17-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.linkedi
n.com/nhome/> (referer: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login)
2013-07-15 12:05:17-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG:


    Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!



2013-07-15 12:05:17-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Hi, this is an item page! http://www.
linkedin.com/nhome/
2013-07-15 12:05:18-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.linkedi
n.com/csearch/results> (referer: http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/)
2013-07-15 12:05:18-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-07-15 12:05:18-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 2171,
     'downloader/request_count': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 87904,
     'downloader/response_count': 4,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 17, 5, 18, 941000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 12,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'response_received_count': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 17, 5, 15, 820000)}
2013-07-15 12:05:18-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 2):

`SgmlLinkExtractor` uses `re` to find matches in link URLs.

What you pass in `allow=` goes through `.compile()`and then all links in pages is checked with  `_matches` which uses... `.search()` on the compiled regex

```
    _matches = lambda url, regexs: any((r.search(url) for r in regexs))
```

See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/sgml.py

When I check your regexes in the Python shell, they both works (they return an `SRE_Match` for URL 1 and 2; I added a failing regex to compare):

```
>>> import re
>>> url1 = 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/1009?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits'
>>> url2 = 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/1033?goback=.fcs_*2_*2_false_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&trk=ncsrch_hits'
>>> regex1 = re.compile(r'\/company\/.*\?goback=.*')
>>> regex2 = re.compile('\/company\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\?')
>>> regex_fail = re.compile(r'\/company\/.*\?gobackbogus=.*')
>>> regex1.search(url1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xe6c308>
>>> regex2.search(url1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xe6c2a0>
>>> regex_fail.search(url1)
>>> regex1.search(url2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xe6c308>
>>> regex2.search(url2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xe6c2a0>
>>> regex_fail.search(url2)
>>>
```

To check if you've got links in the page at all (if everything is not Javascript-generated) I would add a very generic `Rule` matching every link (set `allow=()` or do not set `allow` at all)
See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor

But in the end, you may be better off using LinkedIn API for company search:
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search

Comment: Hey Paul, i don't understand when you enter regex1.search(url1) what does it mean expression it return "<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1902308>" you said the first expression worked. So the second expression did not work? I see the same thing being return regex1 and regex2. The reason I am using scrapy is because i have to extract information on our intranet site and i am using linkedin site as a practice because no one outside my company has access to the intranet site and I won't be able to post the issues i face when extracting data.

Comment: In fact they both work. If you get a SRE_Match it means the pattern was detected. (I'll edit the answer)

Comment: If this is practice for you before working on your intranet web pages, LinkedIn might not be the easiest website to scrape. Have you looked at dmoz.org using in the Scrapy?(tutorialhttp://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It could be interesting to convert the tutorial to use a CrawlSpider

Comment: yes I have use dmoz (I believe dmoz did not follow the links) but i was looking for something that had a login authentication and that uses crawlspider to follow the links, did not have much luck finding it.

Comment: Indeed. Have you tried with the generic Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()) to see if you've got links in your HTML?

Comment: if both worked why it did not show in my output the data extraction?

Comment: use this genetic rule only --> Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor())

Comment: I just tried the generic rule i got the same output as above in my original question no errors but nothing gets scrape

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33564/discussion-between-paul-t-and-gio)